# How to add rescue to simple uri parsing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rescue

I have a simple method that uploads an image from a URL.

```
def photo_from_url(url)
  if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").blank?
    photo_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"]
    self.photo = URI.parse(photo_url)
    self.save
  end
end
```

This works fine in most cases, but sometimes returns `can't convert URI::Generic into String` if the url isn't formatted as expected. I just want to forgo saving the photo in such a case. What do I need to add to the method?

I tried adding

```
rescue => e                                                      
  error_message = e.message                                      
  response_message = "Unknown error"                             
end
```

to the end of the method based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572152/alllow-for-bad-urls-in-in-rails), but this results in a SyntaxError:

```
unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end
```

How/Where do I use the rescue method correctly? Currently, the method works often enough as is, so I'd be happy with it just skipping any unformatted urls, as opposed to returning an error.
Thanks for helping out a newbie.

Comment: What do you mean, "no luck"? Also, you're just setting two local variable that aren't used anywhere. That code doesn't do what you might think.

Comment: Have you made sure to wrap the "risky" code with begin-rescue-end and not just rescue?

Comment: Hi @Sergio, I just added more details.

Comment: @umezo: show full method, with your attempt on exception handling.

Comment: @Magnus, what an easy answer. I feel like an idiot. If you can post that as an answer, I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def photo_from_url(url)
  begin
    if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").blank?
      photo_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"]
      self.photo = URI.parse(photo_url)
      self.save
    end
  rescue => e
    puts "error"
  end
end
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to rescue EVERY error. You should be using `rescue StandardError => e`. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby